# dagger multibinding, Map<java.lang.Integer,? extends javax.inject.Provider<VersionMigration>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, realm, dagger-2, dagger, realm-migration

I am trying to implement Realm Version management with dagger2, with this link [Adavis Realm Migration](http://adavis.info/2017/03/realm-migrations-supercharged-with.html),
but getting following error,

> [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
>   public abstract interface CoreComponent {
>                   ^

The codes are as follows,

```
interface VersionMigration {
fun migrate(realm: DynamicRealm, oldVersion: Long)
}

class RealmVersion1Migration @Inject constructor(): VersionMigration {

override fun migrate(realm: DynamicRealm, oldVersion: Long) {

    val schema = realm.schema

    if (0 == oldVersion.toInt()) {

        schema.create("RealmAlbumEntity")
            .addField("album_id", String::class.java, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)

        Timber.e("migration V1 complete")
    }
}
}

 @Reusable
class ERealmMigration @Inject constructor(
private val versionMigrations:
Map<Int, Provider<VersionMigration>>
) : RealmMigration {

init {
    Timber.e("IN Realm Migration")
}
override fun migrate(
    realm: DynamicRealm,
    oldVersion: Long,
    newVersion: Long
) {
    for (i in oldVersion.toInt() until newVersion) {
        val provider: Provider<VersionMigration> = versionMigrations.getValue(i.toInt())
        val versionMigration = provider.get()
        versionMigration.migrate(realm, i)
    }
}

}
```

This is my included module in realmConfig,
private const val REALM_SCHEMA = 1L

```
 @Module(includes = [MigrationsModule::class])
 class RealmConfigModule {

@Provides
@AppScope
fun provideRealm(realmConfiguration: RealmConfiguration): Realm {
    return Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration)
}

@Provides
@AppScope
fun provideRealmConfiguration(
    @Named(CONTEXT_APPLICATION) application: Application,
    realmMigration: ERealmMigration
): RealmConfiguration {

    val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder().name(application.getString(R.string.real_db_name))
        .schemaVersion(REALM_SCHEMA)
        .migration(realmMigration)
        .modules(UserRealmModule(), EventRealmModule())
        .build()

    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)

    return config
}
```

}

And this is my AppComponent,

```
@Component(modules = [RealmConfigModule::class])
@AppScope
interface CoreComponent {

@Component.Factory
interface Factory {
    fun create(@BindsInstance application: Application): CoreComponent
}
```

}

I had tried to get through following links, but not able to gather any usefull contents out of it.
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399582/dagger2-viewmodel-cannot-be-provided-without-an-provides-annotated-method)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319444/android-arch-lifecycle-viewmodel-cannot-be-provided-without-an-provides-anno)
[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55669810/dagger-missingbinding-java-util-mapjava-lang-class-extends-viewmodel-provide)

Comment: You have used `ERealmMigration` in your **module** but never provide it with it's map content. Then how can dagger handle it?

Comment: Even, i define it in dagger, it still provide me same error, as for now it's a feature called MultiBinding, by dagger2

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple mistake, i just have to add "@JvmSuppressWildcards",

```
 @Reusable
class ERealmMigration @Inject constructor(
private val versionMigrations:
Map<Int,   @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<VersionMigration>>
) : RealmMigration
```

,  thanks to this answer, from this user,

[kotlin + Dagger2 : cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959619/kotlin-dagger2-cannot-be-provided-without-an-provides-annotated-method)